# Use older version of github-release-resource in Concourse using dynamic tag from a file

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-resource-types

GitHub-release resource always emits the latest version. I want to get a specific tag with the version specified in a file.

Below did not fetch the version - `github-release - pinned version tag: path/to/the/file/with/version not found`

```
- get: github-release
  version: 
   tag: path/to/the/file/with/version
  params:
   include_source_zip: true
```

I was able to get the older version by hardcoding the version

```
- get: github-release
  version: { tag : 'v1.0.0' }
  params:
   include_source_zip: true
```

and `fly check-resource -r pipeline/github-release-resource --from tag:v1.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

This is a concourse configuration.
Basically, as stated [here](https://concourse-ci.org/resource-versions.html), you can't really change this on runtime unless you reset the pipeline:

> Pinning through the pipeline config is useful for a more permanent pinned state. If a resource is pinned through the pipeline config, it cannot be modified through the web UI and can only be changed through modifiying and resetting the pipeline config.

Also, the command *fly check-resource ...* is useful in order to verify the version actually exists.